# Is the iphones mac address static? Looking for a way to identify which user is online

Tags: iphone, ios, database, mac-address

I am building an app where I do not want a loginsystem. I still want to be able to know what user is sending information to my online database. As far as I know, the UDID is not allowed to upload to any servers, so that is out of the question. Can I use the iphones mac address for this? If it is dynamic, it will change from time to time, and I won't be able to track it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the MAC address as a unique identifier now the UDID has been deprecated.

MAC addresses are hardware based and therefore cannot be changed.

Comment: What about MAC adress spoofing ?

Comment: Apple seem to have blocked the ability to spoof since iOS 5. Spoofing isn't really changing the MAC address it's just telling the software it's something different.

Comment: I think you can still do it with jailbreak. If you read the mac address in your app, are you sure you won't catch the spoofed one ?

Comment: I guess all the user needs to provide is a unique identifier which either the real or spoofed MAC address will provide. It all depends on how often the spoofed MAC address is refreshed. I guess the other point for discussion is should you be catering for users with jail broken iPhones?