# Grant access to server only with validated IOS devices through Unique Identifier

Tags: iphone, ipad, validation, ios6, udid

I have 10 IOS devices in my company predominantly ipads running IOS 6. I have a server where I've created the appropriate web services for my devices to communicate with. I wish to extend the current setup by only allowing validated devices access to the webservices.

I have looked into passing the UDID as an extra attribute to the web server which would then be run against a database containing encrypted UDIDs and if its found a match then the device is validated and allow the web service process to continue.

However i understand that UDID is now depreciated. What is the easiest way i can implement a unique UDID for each device which would also work for future in-house application updates?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a standard login system whereby the user logs in on the device with a username and password, and then the server returns a certificate that can be used to validate future interactions?  Why restrict users to specific devices when you can just require a login.  The end result - limiting which users can use the system - is still realized, but in a more flexible and extensible way.

Answer (score 1):

Use the UIDevice identifierForVendor to identify the device under iOS6.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]
```

From Apple docs:
"The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps onthe same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardles of vendor."

Another way I have used is to generate a UUID on the server, email it to the user with a URL scheme that opens the app and the app saves it in the keychain. The keychain saves the UUID across app delete/reinstall.

Comment: If user deletes all apps from that vendor, iOS deletes the value. If user re-installs one or more apps after that, a new value is generated. Therefore usefulness of identifierForAdvertising is limited.

Comment: Meant identifierForVendor but that does not solve the problem any better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MAC address of the device. It is not against Apple Policy and it NEVER changes.

Comment: Except when one changes it.

Comment: Don't think that is possible unless you jailbreak the phone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955111/is-the-iphones-mac-address-static-looking-for-a-way-to-identify-which-user-is-o